# How to make responsive to element triangle shape?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want background shape to include triangle shape and I did it with css. I want that to be responsive in every screen size. I am stuck in this . Any advice ...

```css
header {
width: 100%;
height:150px;
background: #eee;
}

main {
width: 100%;
height:150px;
background: #000;
position:relative;
z-index: 1;
}

main::before {
background: inherit;
    top: 0;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 90%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    transform: skewY(-3deg);
    transform-origin: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

main::after {
    border-top: 16vh solid blue;
    border-left: 50vw solid transparent;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    transform: skewY(-3deg);
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    transform-origin: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: -10%;
    }
```

```html
<header></header>
<main>
<main>
```

Expected result in every screen size

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `clip-path - polygon` properties for this.
The issue is, this doesn't support on IE ‍♂️

**More information**

Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path
W3Schools: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_clip-path.asp
CSS Tricks: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip-path/

```css
main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: #000;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
main::before,
main::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
}
main::before {
  background-color: #00f;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 0%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 0%);
}
main::after {
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 75%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 75%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<main><main>
```

Comment: Thank for answer , it is sad polygon not support on IE .

Comment: If you need an answer that also works on IE. I believe you can do this with the SVG image.  Two images are overlapping with each other.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like below:

```css
html::before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 60vh;
  transform-origin: right;
  transform: skewY(-5deg);
  background: linear-gradient(-160deg, blue 15vw, #000 15.2vw);
}
```

Comment: really nice one Thank

Answer (score 0):

I really dont want to answer my own question though, I have been research for about two days and I found something really effective solution. So let me post it .

If I have modify a little bit on `main::after` property , it can be show responsively now.

`transform-origin: 0;` to `transform-origin: -99%;`

`top: -10%` to `top: 0`

That is...